# When to use $(this).text() and when to use $.text([this])

Tags: jquery

A [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856726/jquery-table-row-selector-based-on-user-input) had this as part of its solution:

```
$.text([this])
```

I've never seen that syntax before.  The complete statement was:

```
return $.text([this]).indexOf(myInput) == 0
```

So I'm thinking $(this).text() couldn't be used.

Q: Where is $.text([this]) mentioned in any of the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just more efficient to use `$.text([this])` when you don't need the jQuery object created by `$(this)`.  They do the same thing, just no need to create the jQuery object along the way.

> Q: Where is $.text([this]) mentioned in any of the documentation?

It's not AFAIK, [you're calling `jQuery.text`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L45) which (in the current version) is [just an alias for `Sizzle.getText`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle-jquery.js#L5).

Comment: Doesn't the $ in $.text create the jQuery object?

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn - Nope, you're calling a static method, where as `$(something)` is actually running `jQuery.fn.init(something)`, creating a new object, then you'd be calling `.text()` on *that*.

Comment: No, $ is more or less a "namespace" in this case. It is also a function (in other cases), which when passed a selector returns a jQuery object.